# Can a non-citizen get a pilot job in Canada if they have an FAA CPL?

Tags: airline-pilot, career, canada

I am an Indian national and considering taking CPL classes in the US. Upon graduation I should have around 250 hours under my belt and FAA licenses. Based on my citizenship status and FAA licenses, would any Canadian airline/general aviation employ me? (This is also assuming that I appear for the Canadian license conversion exam, clear it and have my licenses in order.)

Alternately, if anyone knows any other ways to build hours while in the US (like working as a flight instructor on an F-1 visa) please let me know. I need to build a good amount of hours before I can apply to any major air carrier.

Thanks.

Comment: Suggest you go to a site where pilots, not enthusiasts, can answer you questions. [Like this one](https://www.pprune.org/trending.php).

Answer (score 2):

It would be like taking any other job in Canada.  If you aren't a permanent resident/landed immigrant, you need to obtain a temporary work visa with job offer in hand.

In Canada you can hire on with a 2nd tier (Regional) carrier with lower hours than the US because there isn't the "Colgan Rule" that requires 1500 hours (US Regionals have complained bitterly about this, because there are situations where they are forced to take inferior candidates because he/she has the hours, and pass on a superstar that is 500 hours short).

The candidate market is becoming very tight.  Air Canada Jazz operates Q400s and CRJs and is taking pick of the litter kids right out of the colleges and puts them through a more comprehensive training program than the normal two-weeks-then-7-sim-sessions-and-a-checkride whirlwind type course, although off the street candidates will need more time.  West Jet Encore runs Q400s and has dropped their 1500 hour off the street requirement for new FOs down to 1000 hrs and is also running a special mentoring program with the colleges.

Comment: Thank you for this invaluable information. So, off the top I have two more questions to your answer:
1. If I were to get a permanent residency for Canada, would there be a problem then, for the regional airlines to employ me?
2. Does Canada require any other licenses or would my FAA license be enough to apply to the airlines?

Comment: No you would have to have the Canadian Commercial, IATRA exam (for multi-crew, basically an abbreviated ATPL exam) complete, and a Group 1 (multi-IFR) instrument rating.  You should be able to get the conversion from FAA comm multi IFR to Can comm Group 1 with just a conversion exam, but I believe you'd still have to write the IATRA.

Comment: Ok. So if I apply at a Canadian flight school, get accepted, get my licenses then there ideally shouldn't be any issue in hiring me at a regional airliner, correct? If that is so, then it would make more sense for me to get all my training and licenses in Canada itself. Save me some license conversion stress and money.

Comment: If your objective is to live and work in Canada because you want to be in Canada you might as well.  If you already have the funds saved, you might find that although costs are higher, 30K in US funds is 40K in Cdn funds right now so it might work out about the same.  However keep in mind that to fly with a Tier 1 or 2 you would need a Cdn passport which requires citizenship (I imagine the US is the same).

Comment: Thanks. My objective to be honest is not to be in Canada or US as such. But recently I learned that US regional airlines won't employ me unless I have 1500 hours, which I won't get until I get a job in general aviation or as a CFI. And thus, I started looking at Canada as an option. Wondering if Canada also has the same flying hours requirement, and if they would employ me as a CFI if I am not their citizen.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, there is no minimum time like the US, just the required licenses that have their own requirements.  To get a job with low time with a regional you would have to be in one of the colleges they recruit from, and be in the top 10 or 20% of the class.  If you are average you will end up doing it the hard way like most people.  To work in a lower level job that didn't involve international travel, you would just need Cndn licenses and a work visa.